# I need to accurately calculate the brightness of specific area of image data pixels to select the corresponding image

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I have a program that creates Lego mosaics from input images. To choose the right Lego brick color, I calculate the average brightness of the image data pixels in a specific area and then select the corresponding Lego brick. However, this approach often does not yield the correct brick color.

```js
function calculateAverageBrightness(data) {
  let totalBrightness = 0;
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    const r = data[i];
    const g = data[i + 1];
    const b = data[i + 2];

    const brightness = 0.21 * r + 0.72 * g + 0.07 * b;
    totalBrightness += brightness;
    count++;
  }

  return totalBrightness / count;
}
```

Input image - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcxpy.png)
Result image - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2RZz.png)

I want the algorithm to somehow pick right pixel from area of pixels to calculate brightness of it.

Comment: Those two images are identical